# Disabling identity (auto-incrementing) without modifying entity classes (annotations) or datacontext (using fluentapi)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way of disabling (Entity Framework 6+, code first) identity increment temporarily for data-migration purposes without changing `dbcontext` or entities. Is there any Database global property, method etc. or any interceptor injection or any other way to accomplish this.

Let's assume we can not modify the datacontext or entity classes. So I wont be able to use data annotations or fluent API to change identity increment behavior. `DataContext` and entity classes are in another project and should not be modified since they are being used by a some other apps. And all entities use

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

annotation for their ID property.

Is there anyone who has experienced a similar situation or knows how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a special-purpose DbContext subtype that overrides the base configuration in OnModelCreating.

Comment: Thanks for replying David. Do you suggest using FluentApi configurations on derived DbContext for each entity? If so, I do not like to do it. I would have to reflect all new model changes to my new derived class.  And also I do not know if fluent api will override already defined dataannotations. This solution may be my last option.